# Power Automate flow to send a reminder if Due Date is passed

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, date, conditional

I'm working on a Power Automate flow based on a SharePoint list.  I have a Date column (Due Date) and a Choice column (Status) that I need this flow to look at.  Basically what i'm tryign to accomplish is: If the Due Date has passed (based on Today's current Date), AND the Status column = Open, then send an email to the Requestor (person field).

I was originally trying to write the condition to say if the Due Date is less than Today's date...but that doesn't work.

The reason I'm doing this is because this list is substantial (800+ entries), and most entries are both "Open" and passed their due date.  So I need a flow to check all of the entries for these two conditions, and send an email if its Status = Open, AND its Due Date is passed.

Any help would be great...kind of stuck

Thanks!

Comment: Why not Due Date > Today's date?

Comment: When I try this I get an error: "Unable to process template language expressions for action 'Condition' at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'greater' expexts two parameter of matching types.  The function was invoked with values of type 'Null' and 'String' that do not match.'  Not sure what to do with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a scheduled flow that ran once per day. In that flow you could create a variable representing the start of the current day. You can do this using the expression `startOfDay(utcNow())`.

[image]

You could then use the **Get Items** action from the **SharePoint** connector to get all the items where **Status** is **Open** and **Due Date** is less than the date stored in the variable created above.

[image]

Finally, you could use the **Apply to each** action from the **Control** connector to loop through the items returned from the action above and the **Send an email (V2)** action from the **Office 365 Outlook** connector to send the reminder email messages.